# Macbook Pro high CPU temp

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, temperature

I am currently using a macbook pro 16'' 2019 with intel i7.
I am doing some calculation about molecules geometry and wavefunctions with some chemical professional software.
They are very CPU intensive and can use up to 4 core during calculation with OPENMPI.
I've seen with Intel Power Gadget that the CPU temperature is in range 85-96 C degrees.
Is it normal?
Can theese temperatures damage my laptop or there is even the risk of a battery explosion?

Comment: Normally the fans should turn on, and it makes "noise" when the CPU temperature rises. Is this the case?

Comment: No the computer is designed to do this - if it gets too hot the OS will throttle the CPUs back

Comment: If you want to increase the fan speed in order to lower temps you can use Mac Fan control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MacBook Pro is a sophisticated product, with very capable power management and controls to prevent over-heating.

It is designed to be used, and to work hard if needed. You do not need to monitor the temperature, and you cannot damage your computer through use.

Intel CPUs can run over 100˚C quite normally. Your Mac has fans, which will speed up to increase cooling, and the OS will throttle the CPU if it gets too hot. *In extremis*, the CPU will shut off, rather than get so hot that damage might occur.

There is no way that Apple could, or would, sell a laptop whose battery was at risk of explosion as a consequence of high CPU usage. *(Well, not without a recall or a lawsuit.)*